# Google Cloud - Can't find the owner of a project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api

We have some Google Cloud Projects which use Google Calendar APIs and Sheets.
Developers who created this projects have left and their accounts have been deleted. The credentials created by them still work but we can't access those projects in Google Cloud dashboard from any of our existing accounts.

I tried accessing like this: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=project-name-goes-here

All of us get

```
You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page. You are missing the following required permissions:

Project

project-name-here

resourcemanager.projects.get
```

How can an admin can reclaim these projects?
If an account created these projects deleted, will these projects still work?

We don't pay for support so we can't contact anyone from Google Cloud team.

Is there a way to find which Google account do these projects belong to?

Can anyone from Google cloud team clarify?

Thanls

Comment: No, you cannot know who are the owners if you don't have access to the projects.

Comment: I need to pay for technical support for this?
Is there any other way?

Comment: To recover access to the Project, you may check these documents [Recovering administrator access to your account](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/33561?hl=en#:~:text=Go%20to%20the%20https%3A%2F%2F,Click%20Next) and [Allow super administrators to recover their password](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9436964).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Project is under an Organization, the organization is still the owner. You would need to contact the Organization Owners and modify the Owners of the resource.

You can also create a support ticket to the [GCP Account and Resource Recovery Request](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_access_recovery) team